# Postgresql: not explicit behavior of "greater than" operator

Tags: sql, postgresql

I try to fetch all records greater than passed timestamp, but return result contains all records include passed timestamp and I can't explain to myself why that's happened.

Let's say we have a notification record `a` with timestamps - `1562600209.81039`.

I would like to get all notifications greater than notification `a`.
I create a request:

`timestamp_1 = 1562600209.81039`

```
    SELECT notification.id AS notification_id
    FROM notification
    WHERE notification.user_id = %(user_id_1)s AND notification.timestamp > %(timestamp_1)s;
```

I expected the output that has not to include notification record `a`, but I got it.

Comment: `1562600209.81039` is not a "timestamp", that's a decimal value. A timestamp looks like this `2019-08-08 18:41:12`

Comment: You right. I store timestamp as a decimal value in db.

Comment: What data type is that column exactly? `numeric` or `float`?

Comment: Data type is `float`

Comment: Then this might be caused by the fact that float is an approximate data type: http://floating-point-gui.de/ - why don't you use a proper `timestamp` type? It's not only an exact data type but it also makes the queries readable.

Comment: I read article https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xxi-user-notifications#commentform where author shown example of implementation with float instead of timestamp and I took his implementation as a base for my own.
`A notification is going to have a Unix timestamp. The timestamp gets its default value from the time.time() function. The since option with the unix timestamp of the starting time, as a floating point number. Only notifications that occurred after this time will be returned if this argument is included."